# 401 unauthorized with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem. I am trying to pull JSON data with Jquery. But I am getting 401 unauthorized error. I share the link below. Do you have an idea?

> https://tp.grandoption.com/graph/get-option-feed?resolution=raw&assetId=EURUSD&optionId=e731c860-949b-11e6-9c5b-005056911347&accountId=anonymous&_=1476736021687

Comment: Please, take the [tour], learn "*[ask]*" and then read about providing a "*[mcve]*".

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with jQuery. It means the server doesn't want to respond because you haven't supplied the right credentials in the URL, or for some other reason. 401 just means: you aren't authorized to access this webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the correct headers and set withCredentials TRUE in xhrFields:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'https://tp.grandoption.com/graph/get-option-feed?resolution=raw&assetId=EURUSD&optionId=e731c860-949b-11e6-9c5b-005056911347&accountId=anonymous',
        headers: {
            "Accept" : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        },
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
    })
```